# Type mismatch with printfn

Tags: f#

I have a function that concatenates two strings and puts a comma and space between them and returns that. I can't print the result though.

```
let concat first second =
    first + ", " + second


printfn "%s" concat "hello" "world"
```

> Type mismatch. Expecting a     'string -> 'a -> 'b -> 'c'     but given a     'string -> unit'     The type ''a -> 'b -> 'c' does not match the type 'unit' (using external F# compiler)
>
> This expression was expected to have type     'string'     but here
>   has type     'string -> string -> string'

How do I properly print the returned string?

Edit: It seems that I needed brackets surrounding the call to concat. Why was this needed?

```
let concat first second =
    first + ", " + second


printfn "%s" (concat "hello" "world")
```

Comment: The error tells you:
printfn is complaining - it gets `"%s"` and now needs a `string` but gets a  function taking multiple params: `This expression was expected to have type 'string' but here has type 'string -> string -> string'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Robert Nielsen's answer is correct, but let me try a different way to explain it, because if you're new to F# it might be hard to understand an expression like:

```
(((printfn "%s") concat) "hello") "world"
```

So think of it this way: in F#, functions can be passed as input to other functions. For example, you might pass your `concat` function as input to `List.reduce`:

```
List.reduce concat ["one"; "two"; "three"]
// Returns "one, two, three"
```

Now, there are two ways you could read this. Function calls could have left precedence, or right precedence. I.e., if function calls had right precedence, then the `["one"; "two"; "three"]` list would be considered the first argument to the `concat` function (because it's rightmost and thus has precedence). Or if function calls have left precedence, then that list would be the second argument to the `List.reduce` function, and the `concat` function would be the first argument. F# makes the latter (left precedence) the default: in the absence of parentheses, everything after a function's name is considered to be an argument to that function. So the following:

```
printfn "%s" concat "hello" "world"
```

is read as: "call the `printfn` function with four parameters: a string, a function, and two more strings". If you want the strings "hello" and "world" to be arguments to `concat`, you have to add parentheses so that F# will resolve the `concat` call with higher precedence (as you've already discovered):

```
printfn "%s" (concat "hello" "world")
```

This is read as: "call the `concat` function with two strings as parameters, and then take the result of that function call and pass it as the second parameter to `printfn`".

But think about this: if the default was the other way around, and function calls had right precedence — how would you put parentheses into that `List.reduce` example to make it work the way you want? What you want is "Call `List.reduce` with two parameters: the first one is a function, and the second one is a list of strings." But how would you add parentheses to this:

```
List.reduce concat ["one"; "two"; "three"]
```

to get that result? Well, this would work:

```
(List.reduce concat) ["one"; "two"; "three"]
```

But in my opinion, that would be confusing. To understand that expression, you would have to understand how F# currying works, and that's a concept that usually takes a little while to wrap your head around. Whereas with left-precedence function calls, the expression `someFunction a b c` always means "call `someFunction` with three parameters", no matter whether any of those three parameters are functions.

I hope this long-winded explanation has helped you understand F# function calls a little better.

Comment: Your last example probably should be `(List.reduce concat) ["one"; "two"; "three"]` to be as clear as possible.

Comment: I thought of that, but decided that for an F# newbie who may not yet have grokked the concept of currying, that might confuse them more than it would help. **Edit:** Changed my mind. You're right, I should show how it really works.

Answer (score 3):

Because of F-sharp operator precedence: [Symbol and Operator Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/).

Edit: You can think of it as turning

```
(((printfn "%s") concat) "hello") "world"
```

into

```
(printfn "%s") ((concat "hello") "world")
```

but sprinkled with some type inference.